# How to draw a tikz smooth path connecting points on an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-path

I want to draw a "specific" smooth path connecting points on the folowing image [image: figure]

to get [image: this]

All i can do is putting the points on place. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] 
at (-3,-2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{euler.png}};  
\draw [fill=blue] (1.2,1.2) circle (3pt);%A
\draw [fill=blue] (1,-1.9) circle (3pt);%B
\draw [fill=blue] (1.5,4) circle (3pt);%C
\draw [fill=blue] (6.2,.9) circle (3pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `hobby` draws smooth paths through points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest giving the bridges coordinate names. Then you can use the command

`\draw (x) to[out=<angle>,in=<angle>] (y);`

so that the paths go over the bridges.

[image]

I drew red circles to indicate the bridge coordinates, but you can of course remove them by deleting the `\fill[red]...` commands. I also gave coordinate names to your blue circles to make adjustments easier.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] 
at (-3,-2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mOizq.png}};  
\coordinate (a) at (-.25,-.35);
\coordinate (b) at (2.6,-.92);
\coordinate (c) at (.32,2.82);
\coordinate (d) at (3.05,2.75);
\coordinate (e) at (4.3,.88);
\coordinate (f) at (5.3,-.27);
\coordinate (g) at (5.7,2.1);
\coordinate (A) at (1.2,1.2);
\coordinate (B) at (1,-1.9);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,4);
\coordinate (D) at (6.2,.9);
\fill[red] (a) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (b) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (c) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (d) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (e) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (f) circle(2pt);
\fill[red] (g) circle(2pt);
\draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (3pt);
\draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (3pt);
\draw [fill=blue] (C) circle (3pt);
\draw [fill=blue] (D) circle (3pt);
\begin{scope}[line width=1, blue];
\draw (A) to[out=-135,in=60] (a) to[out=-120,in=180] (B) to[out=0,in=-90] (b) to[out=90,in=180] (e) to[out=0,in=180] (D) to[out=-135,in=75] (f) to[out=-115,in=0] (B);
\draw (A) to[out=135,in=-115] (c) to[out=75,in=180] (C) to[out=0,in=60] (d) to[out=-120,in=180] (e) to[out=180,in=0] (A);
\draw (C) to[out=0,in=115] (g) to[out=-75,in=135] (D);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example if using the `hobby` package that can draw smooth curve  through some given points.

[image]

I defined some intermediate points `(A')`, `(A'')` and `(D')`, `(D'')` that help to shape near the two points that are connected via a straight line.  You can adjust those points to obtain the desired shape.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
%\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] 
%at (-3,-2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{euler.png}};  

\coordinate (A) at (1.2,1.2);
\coordinate (A')  at ([shift={(-0.5,  0.5)}]A);
\coordinate (A'') at ([shift={(-0.5, -0.5)}]A);

\coordinate (B) at (1,-1.9);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,4);

\coordinate (D) at (6.2,.9);
\coordinate (D')  at ([shift={(-0.5,  1.0)}]D);
\coordinate (D'') at ([shift={(-0.5, -1.0)}]D);

\draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (3pt) node [above right] {A};
\draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (3pt) node [below left]  {B};
\draw [fill=blue] (C) circle (3pt) node [above left]  {C};
\draw [fill=blue] (D) circle (3pt) node [right]       {D}; 

\draw [red, thick] (D) -- (A)
    to [curve through={(A') (C) (D')}]
    (D);
    
\draw [red, thick] (D) -- (A)
    to [curve through={(A'') (B) (D'')}]
    (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573673/65856), I have arrived at the following.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (-3,-2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{euler.png}};

\coordinate (A) at (1.5,1.3);
\coordinate (A')  at (.2,3);
\coordinate (A'') at (-.2,-0.5);
\coordinate (B) at (1,-1.9);
\coordinate (C) at (1.8,4);
\coordinate (D) at (6.2,.9);
\coordinate (D')  at ([shift={(-0.5,  1.0)}]D);
\coordinate (D'') at ([shift={(-0.5, -1.0)}]D);  
\coordinate (c'') at (3.1,3);
\coordinate (b'') at (2.5,-0.9); 
\draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (3pt) node [above right] {};%{A}; 
\draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (3pt) node [below left]  {};% {B};
\draw [fill=blue] (C) circle (3pt) node [above left]  {};% {C};
\draw [fill=blue] (D) circle (3pt) node [right]       {};% {D};
\draw [blue, thick] (D) -- (A) to [curve through={(A') (C) (D')}] (D);
\draw [blue, thick] (D) -- (A) to [curve through={(A'') (B) (D'')}] (D);
\draw [blue, thick] (A) to [curve through={(b'')}] (B);
\draw [blue, thick] (A) to [curve through={(c'')}] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't know if this could get improved.